# не работает авторизация через ВК

Tags: вконтакте

Помогите исправить авторизацию через вк

```
if($registration_type_conf == 'vk'){
if(isset($_GET['code']) && !$logged)
{
    $result = false;
    $params = array(
        'client_id'     => $vk_client_id_conf,
        'client_secret' => $vk_client_secret_conf,
        'code'          => $_GET['code'],
        'redirect_uri'  => $home_url . 'index.php'
    );

    $token = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);

    if (isset($token['access_token']))
        {
        $params = array(
            'uids'          => $token['id'],
            'fields'        => 'uid',
            'access_token'  => $token['access_token']
        );

        $userInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))), true);
        if (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['uid']))
        {
            $userInfo = $userInfo['response'][0];
            $result = true;
        }
    }if($result){

        $data_query = mysql_fetch_array(do_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id_vk` = " . $userInfo['uid']));

        if($data_query['password'])
        {
            do_query("UPDATE `users` SET `password`='" . $_GET['code'] . "' WHERE `id`=" . $data_query['id']);

            setcookie('user_id', $data_query['id'], time() + 3600 * 24, '/');
            setcookie('password', $_GET['code'], time() + 3600 * 24, '/');

            if($_COOKIE['game'])
                header("Location:" . $home_url . $_COOKIE['game'] . "/" . $data_query['id']);
            else
                header('Location: http://ref-gift.ru/load/index.php');
        }
        else
        {
            file_put_contents("statistics.txt", ++$id_all_user . " " . $all_user_completed);

            do_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `password`, `id_vk`, `reg_date`, `num`, `ip`, `logged_ip`) VALUES ('$id_all_user', '" . $_GET['code'] . "', '" . $userInfo['uid'] . "', " . date('U') . ", '1', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "')");

            setcookie('user_id', $id_all_user, time() + 3600 * 24, '/');
            setcookie('password', $_GET['code'], time() + 3600 * 24, '/');

            save_passwords($id_all_user, '', md5($_GET['code']), $userInfo['uid'], '', '');

            header('Location: http://ref-gift.ru/load/index.php');
        }
    }
}

if(!$logged)
{
    $params = array(
        'client_id'     => $vk_client_id_conf,
        'scope'         => 'offline',
        'redirect_uri'  => $home_url . 'index.php',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'v'         => '5.59'
    );

    $vk_reg = 'http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
}
```

}

Раньше до обновления вк, при клике по кнопке войти через вк открывалось окно с кнопкой разрешить доступ для приложения, а данные о пользователе записывались в бд Mysql, сейчас ничего этого не происходит просто показывается что то типо этого сайт.ру?code=**********

Comment: Что значит «не работает»?

Comment: страница обновляется и вылезает это : http://ref-gift.ru/index.php?code=eb0de0c2175d6a015e

Comment: По реферальным ссылкам мы ходить не будем. Опишите полностью проблему, ожидаемое поведение и фактическое поведение прямо в тексте вопроса, предоставьте [mcve] и текст ошибки, если таковой имеется, включите вывод ошибок в php, если он выключен, пояснит подробнее, кто где обновляется и кто откуда вылезает

Comment: Раньше до обновления вк, при клике по кнопке войти через вк открывалось окно с кнопкой разрешить доступ для приложения, а данные о пользователе записывались в бд Mysql, сейчас ничего этого не происходит просто показывается что то типо этого сайт.ру?code=**********